# Filter timestamp with mongoDb

Tags: python, mongodb

suppose this Json export from my mongoDb

```
{
   "_id":{
      "$oid":"51ca002d9e67460354bb0089"
   },
   "node":{
      "id":"1",
      "components":[
         {
            "sensors":[
               {
                  "name":"backup-job-name",
                  "value":"Job_2"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-job-id",
                  "value":"187"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-start-date",
                  "value":"1372138227"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-stop-date",
                  "value":"1372138235"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-nb-errors",
                  "value":"0"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-nb-warnings",
                  "value":"0"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-source-files",
                  "value":"402"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-source-bytes",
                  "value":"168571449"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-status",
                  "value":null
               }
            ],
            "type":"backup",
            "serial":"1-backup-backup-job-name-Job_2"
         },
         {
            "sensors":[
               {
                  "name":"backup-job-name",
                  "value":"Test_bckp"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-job-id",
                  "value":""
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-start-date",
                  "value":"0"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-stop-date",
                  "value":"0"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-nb-errors",
                  "value":"0"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-nb-warnings",
                  "value":"0"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-source-files",
                  "value":"0"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-source-bytes",
                  "value":"0"
               },
               {
                  "name":"backup-status",
                  "value":null
               }
            ],
            "type":"backup",
            "serial":"1-backup-backup-job-name-Test_bckp"
         }
      ]
   },
   "timestamp":1372192813
}
```

I work with python and i'd like to get documents where "backup-start-date" (stored as timestamp) il greater than a given value.

I've tried with

```
collection.find({
        'node.components.type': 'backup', 
        'node.components.sensors': {'name': 'backup-start-date', 'value': {'$gte': ts_to_compare_with}}}):
```

but any documents in the result. Is my query wrong ?

Comment: Why are your timestamps stored as strings?

Comment: cause it's a remote agent which populates mongo. Is there an operator to convert str to int? Nothing found in the mongo doc. EDIT. even with ts as int, the request fails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things - you are wanting to match an sensor document in the components array and `$gte` only works on integers and dates.

If you convert the data to be ints then you can use `$gte` and query like so:

```
db.test.find({
  'node.components.type': 'backup', 
  'node.components.sensors': { 
      $elemMatch: {'name': 'backup-start-date', 
                   'value': {'$gte': 168571445}}}})
```

Comment: `$gte` is not limited to integers: http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/